# Is it really possible for shared lock query to return incorrect results?

Tags: mysql, database

To make sure we get the latest-consistent result when there are multiple transactions, I use `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. I thought this should fix everything and make sure the data is correct.

Is it really possible that the `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` still return incorrect (non-consistent) results? I'm using MySQL 5.7.26 on RDS.

Comment: It might be better to describe the inconsistencies you're seeing. `lock in share mode` is not a blanket fix.

Comment: I'm trying to count rows of table with certain conditions. And I want to know whether the row exists or not. One condition is based on indexed column, and the other one is not. I received some results where they actually return 0 instead of the real number.